# Triggering an event with a pattern of accelerometer readings

Tags: java, android

I'm making an app that records accelerometer readings and when it recognizes a specific pattern (for example: 3 readings above a threshold in the span of 5 seconds), it triggers an event or a new activity.

My question is what's the best way to implement a method that constantly and consistently "looks" for this pattern?

Comment: implementing SensorEventListener

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a service for that type of application. Here is an example of someone creating a barometer [data logger](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-barometer-logger-acquiring-sensor-data--mobile-10558). There's not really any reason you couldn't use different sensors.

Comment: This is very useful! Thank you.